# Arrays, sorting and binary searching

Tags: c++

Found myself a little stuck with current project. I'm trying to read a .txt file (first and last names separated by space on 1-line each) into an array. After reading in the file this is what is supposed to occur.

- sort the array using a function (I've chosen selection sort)
- ask user to enter a name
- use a function to do a binary search
- display whether name is friend or not if it is found

For much of it I understand. The program was reading in the file earlier and I even wrote it out to display just to see even though it wasnt required. Now it only displays one name. Looking for little help to get me moving again. Apologies if I am a pain in the butt or if my code is jacked up. Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//Function prototypes
void nameSort(string[], const int);

//prototype to display the contents of the file after sorting
//Although I do not need this I wanted to see the names were
//read in correctly.
void nameDisplay(string[], const int);

void nameSearch(string[], const int);
int index = 0; //loop counter

int main()
{
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;
string nameArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
//file object
ifstream fileIn;
fileIn.open("myFriends.dat");

while (index < ARRAY_SIZE && getline(fileIn, nameArray[index]))
index++;
//function call to sort the array
nameSort(nameArray, index);

//Display names to screen as a test of the sort
nameDisplay(nameArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
//function call for search
nameSearch(nameArray, ARRAY_SIZE);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
//function definitions
void nameSort(string *array, const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
bool swap;
string temp;

do
{
    swap = false;
    for (int count = 1; count < (ARRAY_SIZE - 1); count++)
    {
        if(array[count-1] >array[count])
        {
            temp = array[count-1];
            array[count-1] = array[count];
            array[count] = temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
}
while(swap);

}

void nameSearch(string *array, const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
int first = 0;
int last = ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
int middle;
string name;
bool friends = false;

do
{
    cout<<"Please enter a name or END to terminate:";
    cin>>name;
}

    while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (array[middle] == name)
        {
            friends = true;
            cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > name)
            last = middle - 1;
        else 
            last = middle + 1;
    }
} 


void nameDisplay(string *array, const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
    cout<<array[index]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong:  `string nameArray[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];`  Do you want to use two dimensions in order to store first and last names?  I think this would be better:
`string nameArray[ARRAY_SIZE][2];`

Comment: Ideally yes I wanted a single one dimensional array to hold the first and last names like the Tom Jones then next line and another name. The program should hold up to 200 names so would I write the array like this: string nameArray[ARRAY_SIZE][200]?

Comment: The traditional interpretation of a two dimensional array for any type (let's use `string` in this example) is:
`string nameArray[NUMBER_ROWS][NUMBER_COLUMNS]`.  I suggest you declare `nameArray[ARRAY_SIZE][2]`.  Then for person `i`, `nameArray[i][0]` will be the person's last name and `nameArray[i][1]` will be the person's first name.

Comment: After 7+ hours of working on this I figured out looking back over some old program projects from class the getline command. Here is where I'm at now: but it doesn't return the search correctly. Been working on that part for over 2 hours. W

Comment: i feel worthless now. It really feels good when I'm able to finish whatever assignments given but honestly I really do not understand how you guys & gals do this everyday. How long does it normally take to become proficient in a programming language? Sincerely appreciate the help on this.

Comment: Hmmm...thought it would work with your comments but no dice. Back to the drawing board. Think I might scrap what I've got and move back to the 2-dimension array. Seems odd the instructions would say to "read contents of file into array." Figure I'll wait until 4am to start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nameSearch seems to have at least one bug. Instead of:

```
while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (array[middle] == name)
    {
        friends = true;
        cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
    }
    else if (array[middle] > name)
        last = middle - 1;
    else 
        last = middle + 1;
}
```

there should be:

```
while(!friends && first <= last && name != "END");
{
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (array[middle] == name)
    {
        friends = true;
        cout<<array[middle]<<" is my friend."<<endl;
    }
    else if (array[middle] > name)
        last = middle - 1;
    else 
        first = middle + 1;
}
```